# Photoshop CS5 on Ubuntu 10.10 no longer opens after installing Internet Explorer 8

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, photoshop-cs5

I installed Photoshop CS5 in Ubuntu 10.10 using Wine - it was working fine.

Later I tried to install Internet Explorer 8 with Wine. After this, Photoshop is no longer able to load; if I click the icon then nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Tried uninstalling IE8 (and btw why in the world you would want IE8 in Ubuntu...) and/or reinstalling CS5? Also keep in mind that if you want to use Windows software, better switch to Windows. Wine is for software you cannot get in Linux. When you have similar software in Linux, better use that software. In your case you have several replacements for both applications.

Comment: well IE is for testing purpose. I think you need to test web applications on all the browsers. Now the similar softwares(gimp) are not that easy to and effective to work as photoshop. The IE8 was already removed, before asking here for the solution.

Comment: Easy depends on what you're used to. For me GIMP is easier than Photoshop. Anyway you didn't answer: did you try reinstalling it without uninstalling IE8?

Comment: start from the terminal `wine /path/to/photoshop` - what error messages do you get?

Comment: There is no error message. It's just not loading. Not responding